iOS Soft Keyboard Pushes Fixed DIV up instead of dynamically adjusting height
I'm working on a responsive app using React and Tailwind CSS. The layout works as expected on desktop browsers, but I’m having an issue on iOS when the virtual keyboard opens.
When the virtual keyboard opens:

The div (a fixed element) is pushed upwards, hiding the header and top part of the chat window.
The chat window becomes taller than the visible viewport, introducing vertical scrolling (which is not desired).
I want the chat window to dynamically resize to the available space and avoid scrolling.

Steps to recreate it:

Open the app on an iOS device or emulator in Safari.
Resize the window to below 480px width (the chat takes full screen at this breakpoint).
Focus on the text input to open the keyboard.
The header is pushed out of view, and the chat window becomes scrollable.

export const ChatWindow = () => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`
        fixed
        flex 
        flex-col
        z-50
        bg-white
        text-white
        overflow-hidden

        right-[24px]
        bottom-[24px]

        w-[400px]
        min-h-[112px]
        h-[calc(100dvh-48px)]
        max-h-[747px]

        max-[768px]:bottom-[65px]
        max-[768px]:h-[calc(100dvh-89px)]

        max-[480px]:top-0
        max-[480px]:right-0
        max-[480px]:bottom-0
        max-[480px]:left-0
        max-[480px]:w-auto
        max-[480px]:h-[calc(100dvh-env(safe-area-inset-bottom))]
        max-[480px]:max-h-none
        max-[480px]:rounded-none
      `}
    >
      <Header />
      <ChatTranscript />
      <UserInput />
    </div>
  );
};


What I've Tried
Dynamic Viewport Height (dvh): I used dvh for height calculations (e.g., h-[calc(100dvh-48px)]), but it doesn’t seem to update correctly when the keyboard appears.
Custom JavaScript: Dynamically calculated the height using window.innerHeight and applied it as a CSS variable (--vh), but it didn’t fix the issue.
Switching to absolute Positioning Below 480px: Adjusting positioning for small screens didn’t prevent the keyboard from interfering with the layout.
Preventing body Scrolling: I added overflow: hidden to body, but it introduced unrelated layout issues.
Expected:
When the virtual keyboard opens, the div should dynamically resize to fit the available space without being pushed up.
The header should always remain visible.
There should be no unnecessary vertical scrolling.
